# How to prevent inferring generic type arguments with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an API/function that is intended to be used only with generic type arguments (it enforces the shape of an argument based on a generic parameter). I want to prevent calling the API without a generic parameter (thus inferring the type from the arguments), because it defeats the purpose of my function and will be confusing to users of the API. I would rather the compiler just enforce that a generic type argument is *always* required. For example:

```
function foo<T>(arg: Config<T>) { ... }
```

How can I ensure the type argument `T` is always specified by the caller? i.e. `foo<Bar>({ ...})`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a curried function, so that you first call a generic function that has no way of inferring your generic type, and that creates a function with the given type built-in which you can then pass your data to.

For example:

```js
// Just defining this so the example works
type Config<T> = T;

function foo<T = never>(): (arg: Config<T>) => void {
  return (arg: Config<T>) => {
    // Do Something here
    console.log(arg);
  };
}

interface IExample {
  foo: string;
}

// Error - the generic type of `foo` has defaulted to `never`
foo()({ foo: 'bar' });

// No error
foo<IExample>()({ foo: 'bar' });
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECkFcGcBdQCYFMBmBLAdpg5qWALNaUaAez3yVCQA8BDAWwAcAbKgd1ICcBraAKFgBPJlQDCpDOmwAeACoA+UAF5QcgNz9+KSBgDGsNJNApSpeStAYkANyRcFACgCUALlCO6XbO4lS0sorOKko2pGgIoADe-KCgXEiwkFwYHl4+oH7S8grBykoxcXEgoAAi5ADKpAyJhBi4lAmxRXqSZGwAdCyk2J7ezppxAL6aQ1qYsPYodHpUAJIAovTMbNHNpqTucFw4o1olC1xc3KAAtBRU2EjWO3p4IlSkKKAABhsvoPh0xMjTkCyTSKwcgvax2LgvbRmFyOKImMzuADkACMvIjQEMBvswAA5cj2Y5cKHmRbLVhIJzOWHwzagFFojFYoA)

Unfortunately it does make the function a little less tidy, but as far as I'm aware currying functions in this way is the only way to get a greater degree of control over how TypeScript attempts to infer (or require) generic types.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appears to be a functionality yet. That is all that [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) says on generics and inference:

> ```
> function identity<T>(arg: T): T { return arg; }
> let output = identity<string>("myString");  // type of output will be 'string'
> let output = identity("myString");  // type of output will be 'string'
> ```
>
> Notice that we didn’t have to explicitly pass the type in the angle brackets (<>); the compiler just looked at the value "myString", and set T to its type.

And that's basically it... No hint on how to write it so that `identity("myString")` throws an error but `identity<string>("myString")` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question just now, and still not able to rapidly google up the answer, I come up with this option:

```
function foo<Enabled=false,T=unknown>(arg: Enabled extends false ? never : T) {
  // Implementation.
}
```

This way `foo("value")` fails (with default generic arguments `arg` type evaluates `never`, thus forbids any assigment to it); `foo<1>("value")` works (with any value, but `false`, passed into the first generic argument, `T` is auto-resolved based on the type of given `arg` value); and also one can do `foo<1,string>("value")` to force-check whatever type of `arg` which is needed.

---

Perhaps, a better variant:

```
function foo<
  Enabled extends 1 | 0 = 0,
  T = never,
>(arg: Enabled extends 0 ? never : T) {
  // Implementation.
}
```

This way:

- First generic argument is restricted to `1` or `0`, thus if ones forget that the first generic argument is just a switch, not the target `arg` type, it will be immeditely clear, as `foo<string>('value')` fails.
- When `T` defaults `never`, this will also fail: `foo<1>('value')` — even with the function "enabled" by the first generic argument, the `arg` inference does not happen, forcing to specify its expected type via the second generic argument, *i.e.* `foo<1, string>('value')`.